# Eslint react/prop-types vs react/require-default-props

Tags: reactjs, eslint

Can anyone tell me the difference between these 2 eslint rules.

[react/prop-types](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/prop-types.md) vs [react/require-default-props](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/require-default-props.md)

As far as my understanding goes, they both do the same things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**react/prop-types** checks only if there are prop-types set.

**react/require-default-props** enforces the developer to set a default value for each prop.

```
const HelloWorld = ({ name }) => (
  <h1>Hello, {name}!</h1>
);

// eslint react/prop-types will complain if you leave out this block
HelloWorld.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string
};

// eslint react/require-default-props checks for the following block
HelloWorld.defaultProps = {
  name: 'john'
};

ReactDOM.render(<HelloWorld />,  document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 1):

They do *not* do the same thing.

The first one is an eslint-rule to check that used props are also defined in prop-types. The second one is a rule for enforcing the props that **are not** required are set in `defaultProps`